# Understanding spring Hibernate generated sql

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Example 2: One-to-one association that assumes both the source and target share the same primary key values.

```
// On Employee class:

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id Integer id;

    @OneToOne @MapsId
    EmployeeInfo info;
    ...
}

// On EmployeeInfo class:

@Entity
public class EmployeeInfo {
    @Id Integer id;
    ...
}
```

From this example in JPA/Hibernate docs, it indicates same id column from the two tables will be joined.
But when I try this and execute empRepository.findById("123")
the generated sql is

select emp.id from emp left join emp_info on emp.info_id = emp_info.id

But in my DB column name is not info_id, it is "id".
If I explicitly set @MapsId I get below error.
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'. Association in entity is annotated '@MapsId' but refers to a property 'id' which has an explicit column mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your database schema seems to have a different column name (`id`) for the foreign key. To resolve this issue, you need to explicitly specify the column name for the `EmployeeInfo` entity using the `@JoinColumn` annotation.

Try below change in `Employee` entity.

```
    @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "id") // specify mis-matched column name explicitly
    EmployeeInfo info;
```